# Ruby and PHP living together, mass hysteria!

Tags: apache-2.2, php, ruby-on-rails

Is this possible to do in apache?

I need to have a rails site, with a subdirectory controlled by PHP, or have a PHP site with a subdirectory that is a rails application.  Is this possible?

I used to do it all the time in IIS but not sure about apache.

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely possible.

If you're using Passenger in Apache, you're after the [RailsBaseURI](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri) option - follow the link for an example VirtualHost. If you're using a separate Ruby app-server (Mongrel, Thin, etc) then you can just use Apache's mod_proxy to point to the port on which it's running.

Comment: I am using passenger.  I'll take a look at that, thanks.

Comment: So this seems to be able to make a rails site go under a php site.  Is there a way to do the reverse?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Ruby but you can use mod_proxy under apache to send subdirectories to different locations.  So you would have a normal site running php/apache and then proxy /foo to mongrel on a different port.

[Apache Mod_Proxy Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html)